# JQuery Ajax + Dropdown Menu function only runs once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**This function only runs once. How can I get it to run multiple times?**

I have tried using live() as was suggested in another SO question, but that made no difference to the program.

```
$(function() {
  $('#chooseTeam').live('change', (function() {
      $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_get_info', {
            selectedDeck: $('#chooseTeam').val()
          }, function(data) {
                 /* Do something */
          });
      }
    return false;
 }));
});
```

Comment: Reaplce 'live' with 'on'

Comment: I did that - makes no difference - that is what it previously was before I read that live works better wich it did not

Comment: What do you do to make it run? Do you change `#chooseTeam` at all?

Comment: The first time I change the dropdown menu value, it works, not after that, if I change the dropdown menu value, nothing happens

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried with document ready instead of $function()

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#chooseTeam').live('change', (function() {
      $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_get_info', {
            selectedDeck: $('#chooseTeam').val()
          }, function(data) {
                 /* Do something */
          });
      }
    return false;
 }));
});
```

Regards